# When to choose Graphql over REST

Tags: rest, graphql

We currently have an application with various frontends, a backend with a python tornado server, MongoDB and a "REST" API (that isn't very RESTful) so are looking to update to a version 2.

A new start is suggesting GraphQL over REST. I am a little sceptical.

GraphQL does appear more flexible than REST, but that would appear to push more of the logic to the frontend.

In favour of REST:

- It's better understood, with better tooling - things like Swagger are
  available for documentation.
- GET urls can be shared, making debugging easier
- GraphQl sends requests over a POST as far as i can
  tell.

I haven't used GraphQL so I wonder when people would suggest it over REST?

What problems does it solve?

What are the advantages? Obviously being able to query data from the front end seems nice, but I worry that this encourages putting business logic in the frontend.

Answer (score 8):

REST and GraphQL do not play on the same field. What to pick depends of course on your use-case.

If you want to have a database-like access, you probably will lean in the direction of GraphQL. GraphQL is roughly like SQL, it is a language to get data.

If you want independent, scalable components with loose coupling you'll probably lean in the direction of REST. RESTful HTTP is more like a web-application, leading the client through options to achieve a specific use-case or use-cases.

You could also mix the two, if for example a Microservice has a database associated, it could access that database through GraphQL, while offering a RESTful API for to other components for loose coupling.

Side-note: If you're not really doing REST (as you say), i.e. you're not using links, forms, proper media-types, resource discovery/navigation, then the difference becomes really small. Those would be the tools with which loose coupling is achieved, so if you're not using them, and essentially have database-like access anyway, you might as well decide based on personal preference.

Comment: This is for communicating between front end clients (usually web apps) and the main cloud based application.

Comment: That would be an awesome case for REST. I mean the links + forms + navigation type. As I said, if you're doing the usual "query whatever data I want to have at this moment" type of API, then it's basically the same. GraphQL may be slightly more complex, but may cover some cases you want.

Comment: REST seems the obvious choice to me, but I haven't used GraphQL which is why I am trying to get some input from people who have.

Answer (score 4):

### Challenges with GraphQL

Disclaimer: this isn't a fair an balanced examination. This is just the rough edges. There are plenty of good parts as well.

#### Writes

GraphQL has support for writing to the server, called mutations, but it's rudimentary compared to what is available in a web/REST based system. HTTP has three types of write mechanisms, POST, PUT, and PATCH. Each of these has particular guarantees that provide benefits in different cases.

PUT requests are idempotent which gives clients the power to retry a request without worrying about how the second request might break the state of the system. Idempotent PUTs also allow for more efficient caching. An HTTP Cache layer that receives a PUT request can cache that request and use it to respond to subsequent GET requests without having to make a request to the origin server. This is called write-through caching.

#### Concurrency

PUT and PATCH also have concurrency control mechanisms. A request can contain an ETag that identifies that client's previously known state of the resource. If the resource has changed on the server since the request is made, the server can reject the request. This protects against two clients overwriting each other's updates. GraphQL mutations have no concurrency protection mechanisms.

#### Caching

GraphQL is notoriously bad at caching, which has implications for scalability. Since every query can be different, the benefits of caching query results is reduced. Also, GraphQL can't make use of HTTP Cache layers because it tunnels requests through POST. So, caching needs to be done manually on the client and server.

#### Logging / Monitoring

GraphQL also has difficulty making use of existing logging and monitoring tools. With REST, tools can capture what URL was hit, the HTTP method used, the response status code, etc. With GraphQL, you just see a bunch of POSTs to the same endpoint with no clear indication of whether each call was successful or not.

#### Security

When using GraphQL for a public API, you don't have control over what queries API users are executing and therefore can't optimize the system for poor performing queries like you would for a relational database in a closed system. People can conceivably construct queries in ways you haven't thought of that put an unexpected amount of strain on the system.

### Recommendations

Given these challenges, it would be reasonable to consider GraphQL if your API,

- is internal-only (you control all the clients) (see: challenges with security)
- is mostly reads of graph-like data (see: challenges with writing)
- doesn't have the possibility of different clients trying to modify the same resources (see: challenges with concurrency)
- can't be cached effectively (see: challenges with caching)

Generally, I would say you probably want to start with a REST API and if there are parts of you application that fit GraphQL really well, you can always add GraphQL by having your resolvers call the REST API.